# Show that a mapping from one Boolean algebra to another which preserves the operations ⊕ andʹ also preserves the operation ∗.

Tags: boolean-algebra

how do I show that the operations are preserved when mapping from one Boolean algebra to another. Since no Boolean algebra function  is actually given. Thus how do I show this?`

I believe Boolean isomorphism preserves the operations but then how do I prove the above statement in the question.

Comment: *Hint*: $a * b = (a' \oplus b')'$, and if $f$ is such mapping, $f(x')=f(x)'$ and $f(x \oplus y) = f(x) \oplus f(y)$.

Comment: @azif00 thanks I got it!!